# How to copy a struct into a local struct of a thread

Tags: c, multithreading, global-variables

This is my struct:

```
struct example {
    int c=0;
    char buf[10];
}
```

I have a struct of this type allocated in `main()`

```
...
struct example *ex=malloc(sizeof(*ex));
...
```

and passed to a thread by

```
...
pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, t_func, ex);
...
```

pthread_create is called into a child of main.

`t_func` is:

```
void *t_func(void* args) {
   struct example *extmp = args;
   ....
```

How can I create a local `struct example` in every thread and copy into it the struct and the values of args? I need it such that if I modify a field of the local struct, that will not be seen in other threads. I've seen other similar questions, but I haven't found my answer...

Comment: Can't you just malloc another one for each thread and pass in the *pointer, much as you are doing now?  Do you really have to copy it?

Comment: @MartinJames yes, I need to copy, because I need a specular struct for each thread

Comment: @MartinJames can you explain what do you mean with"Can't you just malloc another one for each thread and pass in the *pointer"? maybe in pseudo-code,thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C you can assign objects of structure type:

```
struct example *extmp = args; 
struct example local_copy = *extmp;
```

Comment: Huh. I'm not sure I "didn't know this" as much as "never thought to do it."

Comment: @ouah it doesn't work. if I modify a field of local_copy, will modify the same field of *extmp. it's absurd.why I cannot do that????

Comment: @ouah, I noted that if I do free(&local_copy), it returns warning: attempt to free a non-heap object ‘ex’.that's right, in fact if I increase a local_copy's value, I increase also the same field of *extmp.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a clean, unshared copy for each thread, the place to make the copy is before passing it to the thread. This avoids issues with needing to lock the data.

In your case, the `main` function should malloc another struct, then you can use `memcpy` or `*new_data = *old_data` to copy the data. Then you pass the pointer into the thread.

Now this is the important part. The main thread *should never touch that copy again*. The thread should call `free` when it is done using the data.

Yes, this means that you still have a pointer to a struct and not a struct on the thread stack. However, think about it: what does a struct on the stack get you? You have to type `->` instead of `.` and that's about it.

Of course, my advice gets a lot more complicated and develops exceptions and curlicues if you are doing memory allocation with lock-free per-thread pools or NUMA. In those cases you probably do want to make the copy inside the thread. The main data will need to be locked and the thread will need to make its copy then unlock the data source.

In some exciting case you may need three copies: the primary copy (main memory), a temporary copy (main memory but no need to lock the primary) and the in-thread copy (now in per-thread memory, also no locks).

Comment: +1, but really no need for `memcpy`. A simply copy of `struct` with `=` will always do.

Comment: the fact that pthread_create is called into a child can change something?

Comment: @rschirin: No, but if the main thread and the new thread are using the same data that is a bad idea. Best to make the copy and pass ownership into the thread.